# Automatic use of multi-threading in Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc

I have following problem: 
I work on powerful Intel CPU (8 cores). For this target I compile from source an old in-house C application using gcc. It's single-threded application, so created binary doesn't take any advantage from having multi-core cpu and single core runs at nearly 100% load. Is there some way to utilize other cores without changing source code?

How do I prompt gcc to automatically parallelize the program without explicit multithreaded programming? What hints can I give the compiler in the program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try the gcc flags to auto-parallelize loops (-floop-parallelize-all -ftree-parallelize-loops=8) which uses pthreads. You have to be careful how you write your code of course, the compiler has to know there's no dependance between each iteration of your loop in order to be able to parallelize it.

But to be honest, you get nothing for free, unless your code is designed for multiple processors then you will never gain much.

Comment: Actually, this is DSP application, so it could work. I wasn't aware that this flag uses threads, it was something more related to SIMD instructions for me. I will give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't work for a simple matrix addition which all computations are independent.